# Vinyl plank installation near exterior doorway

Tags: flooring, trim, vinyl-flooring, engineered-flooring

I'm stumped trying to install vinyl plank in an exterior doorway. Our door trim and baseboards are flush - if I undercut the door trim, it seems like I need to undercut the baseboards or remove them altogether? Help most appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: looks like the Lanier Hickory I put down. You can pull off and redo the baseboard, or you can go snug-ish to it and tack on quarter-round or shoe trim to the baseboard, which is what most homes around here are trimmed out with.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of baseboards is to cover up minor imperfections of the fit between floor and wall.

If you're putting in a new floor, it would be best to remove the baseboards, install the floor, then re-install (and re-finish) the baseboards.

It looks like you have a nice floor there to begin with — why not simply re-finish that? You can rent a sander, then put some oil or polyurethane finish on it, and it will look better (and wear longer) than the vinyl planks!

Comment: Baseboards are part of what's called "finish trim". You put it on to provide a finished look _after_ everything else has been done. This answer is spot on!

Comment: Definitely agree with Jan about the refinish & longer wear. We put LVP in a new house built in 2019. The wear (on a very little use home -- 1 elderly lady lives in it) looks like it will require replacement within 2-3 more years. That a 6-7 year life. Next time will be hardwood.